# How to use Python to extract x,y,z coordinates out of a string

Tags: python

I have a string and I need to create a ***dictionary*** of x,y,z coordinates for each point.

Here is what I have tried.

```
data= {}

string = "point {x: 0.4921014904975891  y: 0.27571001648902893  z: -0.4787609279155731}point {x: 0.4930153489112854  y: 0.2628157138824463  z: -0.45403242111206055}"

for i in range(len(string)):
      X_var = "X" + str(i)
      Y_var = "Y" + str(i)
      Z_var = "Z" + str(i)

      data[X_var] = float(string.point[i].x)
      data[Y_var] = float(string.point[i].y)
      data[Z_var] = float(string.point[i].z)
```

The results I am expecting:

```
data = {'X1': 0.4921014904975891, 'Y1': 0.27571001648902893, 'Z1': -0.4787609279155731, 'X2': 0.4930153489112854 , 'Y2': 0.2628157138824463, 'Z2': -0.45403242111206055}
```

The error I am getting

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'point'
```

How can I extract the values I need out of the string?   Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are trying to access an attribute point on string, which is throwing that error. You can use regex to extract points.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You write (emphasis mine) "I need to create a dictionary of x,y,z coordinates *for each* point." yet your expected result is one dictionary containing *all the* points. There's a subtle but major difference and the former is far more useful. Please clarify your expected result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only care about the floats here, you can ignore anything else in the text

So using a regex:

```
dict(zip(["X1", "Y1", "Z1", "X2", "Y2", "Z2",] ,re.findall(r'[+-]?\d+\.\d*', yourinputstring)))
```

if they are not always 2 points you can just construct the dictionary keys with a loop for instance:

```
floats = re.findall(r'[+-]?\d+\.\d*', yourinputstring)
keys = []
for x in range(1, (len(floats) // 3) + 1):
   keys += [f"X{x}", f"Y{x}", f"Z{x}"]
your_dict = dict(zip(keys , floats))
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, it depends on the task. It is preferable to have the correct input data (e.g. JSON).

But if we're talking about parsing current data (always same order of x, y, z values), in a simple way it can be done like this:

```py
data = "point {x: 0.4921014904975891  y: 0.27571001648902893  z: -0.4787609279155731}point {x: 0.4930153489112854  y: 0.2628157138824463  z: -0.45403242111206055}"

data = data.replace("point", "").strip().split(" ")
data = [x.replace("}", "").strip() for x in data]
data = [float(x) for x in data if x and ":" not in x]
data = [data[i : i + 3] for i in range(0, len(data), 3)]
for x, y, z in data:
    print(x, y, z)

# output:
# 0.4921014904975891 0.27571001648902893 -0.4787609279155731
# 0.4930153489112854 0.2628157138824463 -0.45403242111206055
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to retrieve the points from string

```py
import re

# extract points using regex
string = "point {x: 0.4921014904975891  y: 0.27571001648902893  z: -0.4787609279155731}point {x: 0.4930153489112854  y: 0.2628157138824463  z: -0.45403242111206055}"

re.findall(r"point {x: (.*?)  y: (.*?)  z: (.*?)}", string)
```

Output should look like this

```
[('0.4921014904975891', '0.27571001648902893', '-0.4787609279155731'),
 ('0.4930153489112854', '0.2628157138824463', '-0.45403242111206055')]
```

Further you can convert those points into float to use as you want.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I am unclear for how to get to a dictionary like in the example. 

data = {'X1': 0.4921014904975891, 'Y1': 0.27571001648902893, 'Z1': -0.4787609279155731, 'X2': 0.4930153489112854 , 'Y2': 0.2628157138824463, 'Z2': -0.45403242111206055}

Comment: You have a list of tuples containing 3 items each. You should be able to figure out how to convert each tuple to a dict without too much trouble. As a starting point look at `enumerate`

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest, but this method parses the string to add commas and the proper names for the keys and uses `ast.literal_eval` to add the points to a dictionary:

```py
from ast import literal_eval
import re

string = "point {x: 0.4921014904975891  y: 0.27571001648902893  z: -0.4787609279155731}point {x: 0.4930153489112854  y: 0.2628157138824463  z: -0.45403242111206055}"
data = {}

for i, point in enumerate(string.upper().split('POINT')[1:], 1):      # capitalizes keys, splits on every point keyword
    comma_added = re.sub(r'(?:\d) ', r',', point).lstrip()            # adds comma after every float
    keys_formatted = re.sub(r'([A-Z])', fr'"\g<1>{i}"', comma_added)  # replaces X with "X1" for instance
    data.update(literal_eval(keys_formatted))                         # evaluates the parsed dictionary and updates data

print(data)
```

Output:

```py
{'X1': 0.492101490497589, 'Y1': 0.2757100164890289, 'Z1': -0.4787609279155731, 'X2': 0.493015348911285, 'Y2': 0.262815713882446, 'Z2': -0.45403242111206055}
```